# Steam Controller stops working after few minutes

Tags: 16.04, hardware, steam

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm using a Steam Controller. As soon as I plug it in, it usually works for few minutes and then stops working. It just stops taking input from the controller: can't use the pad to control the mouse cursor, can't select anything with any button, etc. The steam logo is still lit up and strangely, the haptic feedback still works on the pad.

Sometimes I get this after 1 min, other times it takes 5 min. It doesn't matter if I start Steam, if I run it in Big Picture Mode or if I'm playing a game or not. It's always the same.

I have a dual boot machine, so naturally I checked if the same problem occurs on Windows 10. It works flawlessly, no problems ever encountered. The issue seems to appear only on Ubuntu systems. I tried different USB slots, even a different machine with Ubuntu 16.04. It's the same.

I tried installing several versions of the firmware using [this](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=572740074) post. It makes no difference. I even tried to change the /lib/udev/rules.d/99-steam-controller-perms.rules as suggested by [this](https://steamcommunity.com/app/353370/discussions/0/490123197945710268/) post, still the same issue.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Thanks!